# Displaying path and line number in log file in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, logging

I want to implement error handling and maintain log file to record errors in my CodeIgniter application.

In general, CodeIgniter doesn't record the error message along with the path and line number in certain cases like database exceptions or custom error logging. This is difficult to trace. So is there any way to log the error along with the path and line number?

Answer (score -1):

Codeigniter provide logs with date time and path of a file. You can follow this instruction:

1. application->config.php
   and changed the following values as per your requirnment 
   log_threshold
   log_path
   log_file_extension

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the solution you suggested is not related to my problem. My point is, how to show the path and line number in the log file along with the error message.  For eg:  ERROR - 2017-09-16 15:04:49 --> Query error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table (title) VALUES('hello')' at line 1 - Invalid query: INSERT INTO table (title) VALUES('hello'). Here file path and line number is not given which is difficult to identify.

Answer (score -1):

CodeIgniter has some error logging functions built in.

Go to application/config/config.php

set

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 1;
```

Note

your /application/logs folder should be writable

Comment: I want to see the path and line number with the error message in the log file, which will be easy to trace.